# Splitting data from excel worksheet into multiple workbooks based in a column value

Tags: vba, excel

I'm using this code (from [Splitting worksheet into multiple workbooks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26144525/splitting-data-from-excel-worksheet-into-multiple-workbooks/38744297#38744297)) and the code works wonders when I use a short database to be filtered in column 3. However, I have a database where the column to be used as filter, aka *field*, is in the 35 column or "AI" and in this case the code doesn't work. So, this code just creates the workbooks depending on the value of the filtered column (good) but the data itself is not filtered, creating (in this case) three identical files. Any Suggestions? This is the code I used:

```
Sub CreateBatchWorkbooks()

On Error Resume Next
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("CalcData")  'Replace the sheet name with the raw data sheet name

Set Newsheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("cal")

    If Newsheet Is Nothing Then
            Worksheets.Add.Name = "cal"
        Else
            ThisWorkbook.Sheets("cal").Delete
            Worksheets.Add.Name = "cal"
    End If

        FilterField = WorksheetFunction.Match("BatchNumber ()", ThisWorkbook.Sheets("CalcData").Range("1:1"), 0)

        .Columns(FilterField).Copy

            With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("cal")
                .Range("a1").PasteSpecial (xlPasteAll)
                .Columns("a").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlYes
            End With

                    For Each cell In ThisWorkbook.Sheets("cal").Columns("a").Cells
                        i = i + 1
                            If i <> 1 And cell.Value <> "" Then
                                .AutoFilterMode = False
                                .Rows(1).AutoFilter field:=FilterField, Criteria1:=cell.Value
                                Set new_book = Workbooks.Add
                                .UsedRange.Copy
                                new_book.Sheets(1).Range("a1").PasteSpecial (xlPasteAll)
                                new_book.SaveAs Filename:=ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & cell.Value & ".xlsx"
                                new_book.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Columns.AutoFit
                                new_book.Save
                                new_book.Close
                            End If
                    Next cell

                        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("cal").Delete
End With

End Sub
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Get rid of `On Error Resume Next` (See [Documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/vba/3211/error-handling/11022/resume-keyword)). Because of this line, any error you're getting in your code is being totally ignored. Report back any error messages (edit your post to include them) you're getting. Then read the rest of that Documentation section on error handling. There is _almost_ **never** a good reason to use OERN.

Comment: Also, you are trying to filter field #35 on a one column range.  The previous post you linked to shows this correction in the comments.

Comment: I just updated the code. Still nothing is being solved. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. I post it in here in case is of help for somebody using named tables or databases :)

```
Sub CreateBatchWorkbooks()

On Error Resume Next
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("CalcData")  'Replace the sheet name with the raw data sheet name

Set Newsheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("cal")

    If Newsheet Is Nothing Then
            Worksheets.Add.Name = "cal"
        Else
            ThisWorkbook.Sheets("cal").Delete
            Worksheets.Add.Name = "cal"
    End If

        FilterField = WorksheetFunction.Match("BatchNumber ()", ThisWorkbook.Sheets("CalcData").Range("1:1"), 0)

        .Columns(FilterField).Copy

            With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("cal")
                .Range("a1").PasteSpecial (xlPasteAll)
                .Columns("a").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlYes
            End With

                    Dim rngFilteredCalcData
                    For Each cell In ThisWorkbook.Sheets("cal").Columns("a").Cells
                        i = i + 1
                            If i <> 1 And cell.Value <> "" Then
                                Set rngFilteredCalcData = .ListObjects("tblCalcData").Range
                                rngFilteredCalcData.AutoFilterMode = False
                                rngFilteredCalcData.AutoFilter field:=FilterField, Criteria1:=cell.Value

                                Set new_book = Workbooks.Add
                                rngFilteredCalcData.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Rows.Copy
                                new_book.Sheets(1).Range("a1").PasteSpecial (xlPasteAll)
                                new_book.SaveAs Filename:=ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & cell.Value & ".xlsx"
                                new_book.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Columns.AutoFit
                                new_book.Save
                                new_book.Close
                            End If
                    Next cell

                        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("cal").Delete
End With

End Sub
```