# Split data into multiple Workbooks based on column

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to split my data into multiple excel files that will carry the name of my "unique value". I usually perform this task every day.

I have about 50 columns, column A contains the unique value, which can be repeated several times. The other columns carry information regarding the unique value. I would also prefer if the original formatting of the file remains.

I have the macro which is splitting the data within workbook (multiple worksheets). But I want to split the data into different workbooks. If possible, save the different workbooks with unique value name.

Code: `

```
Sub parse_data()
Dim lr As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim vcol, i As Integer
Dim icol As Long
Dim myarr As Variant
Dim title As String
Dim titlerow As Integer
vcol = 1        
Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")        
lr = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, vcol).End(xlUp).Row
title = "A1:C1"            
titlerow = ws.Range(title).Cells(1).Row
icol = ws.Columns.Count
ws.Cells(1, icol) = "Unique"
For i = 2 To lr
On Error Resume Next
If ws.Cells(i, vcol) <> "" And Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(ws.Cells(i, vcol), ws.Columns(icol), 0) = 0 Then
ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, icol).End(xlUp).Offset(1) = ws.Cells(i, vcol)
End If
Next
myarr = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(ws.Columns(icol).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants))
ws.Columns(icol).Clear
For i = 2 To UBound(myarr)
ws.Range(title).AutoFilter field:=vcol, Criteria1:=myarr(i) & ""
If Not Evaluate("=ISREF('" & myarr(i) & "'!A1)") Then
Sheets.Add(after:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)).Name = myarr(i) & ""
Else
Sheets(myarr(i) & "").Move after:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)
End If
ws.Range("A" & titlerow & ":A" & lr).EntireRow.Copy Sheets(myarr(i) & "").Range("A1")
Sheets(myarr(i) & "").Columns.AutoFit
Next
ws.AutoFilterMode = False
ws.Activate
End Sub`
```

Comment: Show us what you have tried to accomplish your stated task.  What has gone wrong?  I would also suggest you indent your code so it will be more readable.  In the long run, this will make debugging much simpler.

Comment: Just save the new worksheet (sheets.add) to a new workbook.  Why do you name the sheet myarr(i) & ""?  What is the & "" for?

Comment: @mooseman I tried to run the above macro and it is throwing an error 'runtime error 13 type mismatch'  for 'For i = 2 To UBound(myarr)'. Please help me in error to be fixed.

Comment: Also, I can correlate my problem with one of the questions that have been asked earlier in stack overflow.

Comment: Also, I can correlate my problem with one of the questions that have been asked earlier in stack overflow. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26144525/splitting-data-from-excel-worksheet-into-multiple-workbooks. But the problem is, the macro is saving the code itself in spite of saving the data in multiple excel file with name Book 1, Book 2 ..etc.

Comment: Please help me with this problem.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your posted code above came from www.extendoffice.com

A simple google search turned up more code on that site that does what you ask for:

https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/1174-excel-split-data-into-multiple-worksheets-based-on-column.html#a1